# Including "ID" in a model's attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes

I have an attribute that saves the Playstation Network ID for a user in my `User` model named `psn_id`. I was wondering if it were best practice to include `id` in the name considering that appending that particular word is usually reserved for primary and foreign keys. Will it cause any problems somewhere down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't cause you any problems. ActiveRecord will not try to do something funny just because name of your attribute ends with `_id`, it would be silly.

Moreover, if later on you decide to have a `Psn` model, you can just add a

```
belongs_to :psn
```

and it will "just work", using your existing `psn_id` attribute to refer to the related PSN profile object.

BTW, don't create a `Psn` model, it sounds confusing. If you needed to create a model here, it would be more `PsnProfile`, right? In which case you can do this.

```
belongs_to :psn_profile, foreign_key: 'psn_id'
```

A bit more verbose, but will work.